# How is the IMU used in the PixHawk?

Tags: imu, uav

Looking at [3DR's Pixhawk hardware on GitHub](https://github.com/3drobotics/Pixhawk_OS_Hardware) the FMU and IMU are treated as different pieces of hardware. On the schematics for the FMUs ([example](https://github.com/3drobotics/Pixhawk_OS_Hardware/blob/master/FMUv3_REV_G/Schematic%20Print/Schematic%20Prints.PDF)) there is limited reference to the IMU.

So, is the IMU a separate board inside the Pixhawk? Is there information somewhere that shows which IMUs come with which FMUs?

Comment: what does it say on the PixHawk website?

Answer (score 2):

Take a read [here](http://ardupilot.org/copter/docs/common-px4fmu-overview.html) and [here](https://docs.px4.io/en/flight_controller/pixhawk_series.html).
The Flight Management Unit (FMU) board and the IO board combined make a Pixhawk autopilot.

The FMU is contains the control logic and the sensors while the IO takes care of the IO (duh) and some failsafe functionality which is best kept separate from the main loop.

Recent Pixhawk versions contain more advanced versions of the FMU board which hosts more than one IMU sets. To be more specific, they are populated with 2 or 3 separate accelerometers, gyroscopes and magnetometers.
I'm not 100% clear if they use 3 9DOF chips or 9 3DOF chips to achieve this; it may vary from FMU version to FMU version.

That said, the FMU hosts one (or more FMUs) and not vice versa.